# Evaluating the following integral: $ \iiint_R x \, dA$ using a change of variable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm calculating the following integral: 
$$ \iiint_R x \, dA$$

Where $S$ is the region in the first quadrant delimited by the portion of the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ and the lines $y=1$ and $y=2$. This specific problem suggests to use the variable change: $u=x^2+y^2$, $v=x^2-y^2$. However, I don't know how to express the area $S$ using this new variables. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\iint_{\rm S}x\,\dd y\,\dd x}&
=\int_{0}^{\root{3}}\int_{1}^{\root{4 - x^{2}}}x\,\dd y\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{\root{3}}x\pars{\root{4 - x^{2}} - 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{3}\pars{\root{4 - x} - 1}\,\dd x
=\half\bracks{-\,{2 \over 3}\,\pars{4 - x}^{3/2} - x}_{0}^{3}
\\[5mm]&=\half\pars{-\,{2 \over 3} - 3 + {2 \over 3}\,4^{3/2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{5 \over 6}} \approx {\tt 0.8333}
\end{align}

Comment: I had figured it out and got to the same answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez You are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $y=\sqrt{\dfrac{u-v}2}$ for $y>0$.

Comment: Thanks, with that I get 4=u-v,1=u-v, and u=4, I just need one more condition to get a geometrical figure.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Are all the data correct? I have just noticed, that radius of the circle should be rather greater than 2, if one of the lines is $y=2$.

Comment: You are right. That is how it is written but it must be a mistake.

Comment: This problem is correct actually. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This region is perfectly defined for the circle of radius $2$ because $y=2$ lies tangent to the circle. Perhaps it's more intuitive to define the region as bounded below by $y = 1$ and above by $x^2 + y^2 = 4$. Since the region is inside the circle, this means $0 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4$, or $0 \le u \le 4$. The other condition is:

$$ 1 \le y \le 2 \Rightarrow 1 \le y^2 \le 4 \Rightarrow 1\le \frac{u-v}{2} \le 4 \Rightarrow 2 \le u - v \le 8 $$